# Postgresql driver error

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, persistence.xml

I have this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="project-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>model.Product</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="postgres" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="xxx" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="postgres" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                                                     value="buildSchema(SchemaAction=add,ForeignKeys=true)" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This main

```
import model.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class pruebaMain {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("project-unit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("cheese");
        product.setCode(21421);
        product.setDescription("Test description");

        EntityTransaction tx= em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(product);
        tx.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }

}
```

and this product class:
package model;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
long code;
@Column(nullable=false,length=50)
String name;
@Column(nullable=false,length=500)
String description;
@Column(nullable=false)
int stock;

//builders
public Product(){
    this.code=0;
    this.name="";
    this.description="";
    this.stock=0;
}
public Product(long code, String name, String description,int stock){

    this.code=code;
    this.name=name;
    this.name=description;
    this.stock=stock;
}

//get & set
public long getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(long code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}



}
```

But , when I try the code , I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@442ce698". 
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:849)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:602)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1518)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:535)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:460)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:121)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:967)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:958)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:642)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:202)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at pruebaMain.main(pruebaMain.java:10)
```

I dont know what is the problem . I specified the ConnectionDriverName and I added to build path : postgresql-jdbc4.jar , postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it . I had the persistence.xml in a wrong folder, now it is in META-INF and it works!

Comment: You should not need to specify `openjpa.ConnectionDriverName` anymore. JDBC should find it automatically for you these days, based upon the connection URL.